# Change local time to the UTC+0 using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, utc

I have a string date value:

```
const date = "2019-08-19T00:00:00Z";
```

This is my local time that actually stands for:

```
Tue Aug 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

How can I use the `moment.js` library to convert this date string to the UTC+0? I tried using the `utc()` function but it works the opposite way I intended (it treats the `date` value as UTC+0).

Comment: Your "date" string is midnight UTC (GMT), not GMT + 2. It *doesn't* stand for your desired local time, in other words. *edit* also the date is several days off.

Comment: Yes, it is midnight in my local time. I want to achieve the ```date``` equivalent for ```Tue Aug 26 2019 22:00:00 GMT (Central European Summer Time)``` using moment.js

Comment: Clarification: the date string you posted ends in "Z".  That means it's UTC, not GMT+2. Also it's August 19, not August 27.

Comment: If you want to take a UTC time string and adjust it, just parse it and then add 2 hours via the `.getHours()` and `.setHours()` APIs on the Date instance.

Comment: So you just want to change "Tue Aug 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200" to "Tue Aug 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000"? As Pointy said, "2019-08-19T00:00:00Z" is already GMT+0000, that's what the Z means.